# Should I access (not change) an object from multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

My situation is that I have two threads. The 1st thread produces a number of objects which the 2nd thread does not have access to until all of them are created. After that the 2nd thread reads fields in those objects but does so concurrently with the 1st. At this point no thread is changing the values of the fields of the objects.
The objects are not synchronized. Should I synchronize them or not?

Comment: You can have any number of threads reading the same data without thread safety issues.

Comment: @BheshGurung page not found. Just remove some of the text at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would recommend is to use an `AtomicReference<Collection<SomeObject>>`.  The first thread would produce the collection of objects and do a `reference.put(collection)`.  The 2nd thread would see the objects (`reference.get()`) after they have been set on the `AtomicReference` only.  Here are the [javadocs for `AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).  You could also set your objects as an array or any type of collection such as `List`.

If is important to realize that after your set the collection (or array) on the `AtomicReference` you cannot make any changes to the collection.  You can't add additional items, clear it, etc..  If you want true concurrent access to a collection of objects then you should look into [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and friends.

> Should I synchronize them or not?

If the objects are not going to be mutated at all *after* they are put in your collection then you do *not* need to make them synchronized.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with reading data from multiple threads at the same time.  Issues arise when you attempt to modify that data.  So long as the objects are fully initialized and the values are such that the second thread receives the actual value (no issues with caching etc), there no problem with reading data from multiple threads concurrently.